# Foalts Server-sent Event

Tags: typescript, express, foalts

I love foalts and I am currently using it in a project. But I have feature that requires server-sent events (SSE) but I am not able to implement a response.write on the return response. But I am able to write the headers to have "**'Content-Type', 'text/event-stream'**"

The only challenge is creating a new res.write()

```js
res.write(sseFormattedResponse); // express example
```

Thank you for your assistance in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can create a `ReadableStream`, named for example `myStream`, and create with it a `HttpResponse` as follows:

```
return new HttpResponseOK(myStream, { stream: true })
```

or in you case:

```
return new HttpResponseOK(myStream, { stream: true })
  .setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
```